# Debugging semi-sporadic network timeout errors with Golang HTTP requests

Tags: go, debugging, networking, timeout

in one of my projects at work, I have a Service A that has a cronjob running every minute, that makes a total of 2 requests to my service B. One is a request to get auth tokens, while the second is to get some business data using the auth token.

The problem is that awhile after Service A is deployed (a few days), requests to Service B start taking very long - more 10 seconds, which is the timeout i configured, resulting in `context deadline exceeded (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)` errors. Sometimes the error is not this, but that the response body and cookies in the response are empty. Once these errors start, they do continue to happen most of the time, with some periods of time in between where it goes back to normal.

Tge client that is producing this problem is simply initialised as `&http.Client{Timeout: 10 * time.Second}`. I'm currently investigating if using longer idle timeouts like:

```golang
maxConn     = 100
dialTimeout = 30 * time.Second
readTimeout = 10 * time.Second

idleTimeout = 2 * time.Minute

func initHttpTransport() *http.Transport {
    t := http.DefaultTransport.(*http.Transport).Clone()
    t.MaxConnsPerHost = maxConn
    t.MaxIdleConnsPerHost = maxConn
    t.IdleConnTimeout = idleTimeout
    t.DialContext = func(ctx context.Context, network, addr string) (net.Conn, error) {
        return (&net.Dialer{
            Timeout:   idleTimeout,
            KeepAlive: idleTimeout,
        }).DialContext(ctx, network, addr)
    }
    return t
}

httpClient := &http.Client{
    Transport: initHttpTransport(),
    Timeout:   readTimeout,
}
```

solves this issue, but I'm still waiting to see if the problem still persists. In the meantime, I would like to ask for advice on how i can possibly try to reproduce this problem, and/or any possible ideas on how to investigate and solve the issue, possibly on the server side as well (which i have control over, for both services).

Thanks!

Comment: We can't say much without a complete minimal reproduction of the behavior.  My first guess would be that you're not closing your connections.  Sounds like Service A runs only for a few seconds of every minute and has no persistent state, so if that's true, your leaking connections or other resources are in service B.

Comment: @erik258 hmm just to clarify, do u mean that service B is leaking connections/resources? For additional context, manual requests to Service B still work fine when Service A experiences the issues highlighted above.

Comment: That seems like the obvious guess, since from your description Service A isn't long running.  We can only guess with the information you've provided us